# Java did not install complete Error code 1603 (JRE Upgrade from version 8.0.381 to version 8.0.391)

Tags: java

**Problem Description:**
I have downloaded the offline installer, jre-8u391-windows-x64.exe (version 8.0.3910.13). However, during the upgrade process, I am consistently encountering an error: Java did not install complete Error code 1603.

**Context:**

Operating System: Windows Server 2016
Installer Version: jre-8u391-windows-x64.exe (8.0.3910.13)

**Issue Details:**

Upon running the installer, it begins the installation process but fails with the error code 1603. I've attempted this multiple times, but the result remains the same.

Cleaned Temporary Files and checked Windows Installer Service is running

Comment: Uninstall the existing JRE, delete the installation folder and retry?

Comment: If you do not have any specific requirement that it *must* be the Oracle Java8, go e.g. to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html , download the Windows ZIP, decompress anywhere, adjust PATH (if necessary) and you can run Java from the decompressed folder.